# Formula for workflow rule using a date function and User comparison isn't triggering

Tags: workflow, formula

My requirement is that a workflow rule should fire and send email to the concerned people. But my workflow rule doesn't fire nor send any email when I use a specific formula which compares a `date function <> null and LastModifiedBy.ID = Some User ID`.

But it fires when I use the date function alone in either of the criteria are met option or formula.

Here are the three workflow formulas which I've tried but neither of them didn't fire as expected,

```
AND(Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c != Null,$User.Id == Auditee__r.User__c)
```

---

```
AND(Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c != Null,$User.Id == Auditee__r.User__c)
```

---

```
AND(ISNULL(Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c), LastModifiedBy.Id = Auditee__r.User__c)
```

Please tell me how should I handle this workflow rule so that ti triggers successfully.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using something like this- AND(NOT(ISNULL(Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c)), $User.Id = Auditee__r.VanaHCM__User__c)

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an order of execution issue?  Where the the WFR doesn't know the context of $User or LastModifiedBy at the time of fire.  Can you try something like comparing OwnerID to Auditee__r.User, just to see if the logic works?

Comment: @ Prabhat Kumar Thank u, your formula worked for me and I'm able send mails via my WFR. Thanks once again guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this- AND(NOT(ISNULL(Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c)), $User.Id = Auditee__r.VanaHCM__User__c) – Prabhat Kumar 17 hours ago